# Current in a two capacitors system in parrallel

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, charge, capacitance

[image]

I solved this question and I got the values of charges on capacitors in figure B. But my question is charge on capacitors is getting redistributed,but how is it possible when potential difference between the capacitor is zero since they are at equal potential. So there is no chance of charge flowing in the circuit.please help me with the physics behind this

Answer (score 0):

When dielectric is added, concentrate on that capacitor only, the only thing that remains constant on addition is charge of the capacitor. The capacitance and voltage difference change accordingly.

Now you can apply $Q=CV$, and you can find new capacitance and hence the voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the dielectric into the left hand capacitor lowers the pd between its plates. The electric field between the plates polarises the dielectric, so on the faces of the dielectric next to the plates, charges appear which are of opposite sign to those on the adjacent plates. So the electric field between the plates is reduced, and therefore the pd between the plates, even though the charges on the plates themselves remain the same at first. [Here I'm assuming that there's resistance in the connecting wires, so the capacitor can be considered isolated immediately after the dielectric is inserted.]

The pds across the two capacitors are now different and charge will flow until the pds across the capacitors are equal. Using this condition (equal pds, knowing that the left hand capacitor now has capacitance $\kappa C$) and conservation of charge, you arrive at the answer!

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Can you also help with Formulating mathematical equation for relationships between Q and V

Comment: In figure B, $Q_1=\kappa C V$, $Q_2=CV$ in which $V$ is the final pd across each capacitor. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: Sorry actually relationship between  Q and time

Comment: For this request to make sense, you need to have a non-zero resistance in at least one of the wires linking the capacitors. Can you see why, and do you want to pursue this further?

Comment: Yes I did same introduce a resistor R in circuit but I am stuck in finding the relationship between Q and time

Comment: Let charge on left hand capacitor at time $t$ after inserting dielectric be $q$. Then charge on right hand capacitor at time $t$ is $2Q-q$. So you can now write down the pds across the two capacitors at time $t$. Now write down the Kirchhoff's second law equation for the circuit. This can be written as a differential equation, since $IR=R\ dq/dt$. Can you solve it?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll do the D.E part on my own